# How Do I Fade Out 3D Tilemap Tiles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying to fade out the tiles whenever I click play/level starts but I cant seem to just this layer of tiles from the map. If I try to change the actual alpha value under Animation Frame rate it does nothing. I am trying to just have the tiles fade out after a set time. Each tile is a prefab.

[Scene View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDMQy.png)

I am just trying to fade the disappearing tiles and leave the start and end tiles alone.

I tried to change the color and it didn't work. I tried to change the albedo value of the shader but it just changes them all. I tried to create a script but it did nothing as well. I just want all the tiles under the disappearing tiles parent to fade out.